# Get all filenames in my server(Remote)

Tags: php

I am able to run this file on my local setup and get all file-names, but unable to run it on the webserver.

here is my code:

```
$log_directory = getcwd()."/Episode".$epNum;
$dir = "/images/Episode1";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($log_directory)){
  if ($dh = opendir($log_directory)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure on the remote server you have the desired directory.

Comment: meaning http://myservername.com/thisfolder/folder2/?

Comment: yes, and `$dir = "/images/Episode1";`

Answer (score 2):

hey you can use below code to get all folder name inside in any directory

```
  <select   >
  <option value="">Select folder </option>

  <?php $dir = 'mainfolder'; //this is your main dir 
  $files = scandir($dir, 0);
  for($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++)//the below code will show aall folder name inside the folder "mainfolder"
     {
  ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $files[$i]; ?>" ><?php  echo $files[$i]; ?> </option>

  <?php
     }   
  ?>
```

Comment: my main issue is the dir what should I put in?

Comment: can you please explain more then i can resolve your problem

Comment: "?php $dir = 'mainfolder'" What should I put here? http://mysampleserver.com/myfolder/folder/?

Comment: its depend on your location of your php page suppose index.php  is your running code and let index.php is in myfolder and folder with name "folder" is also in myfolder then you have to put $dir="folder" irt will show the all folder list inside the "folder"  if you want to all folder list inside the "myfolder" then you will use $dir="../myfolder" and use condition if(is_dir($files[$i])){ to check if it is dir

Comment: It worked, but how can I display the filenames in it with extention?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110871/discussion-between-ram-singh-and-vonncc).